# How to export an image as form data using VBA macro with an API and VB macro?

Tags: vba, macos

I am trying to export an image to a Mongo DB using an API , and VB macro.
When I use the API with postman , it is working ( The image will be added as a file under - form data).
Now , I need to automate this using the VBA  - ERStudio macro .

I have written the below code to do the same, even though there is no error, image is not exported.

### In the below code, the API has been masked as -"optionalURL"

```
    Const PATH = "C:\Test\600001453\"
    Const FILENAME = "Image.png"
    Const CONTENT = "image/png"
    Const URL = "optionalURL&carid=00000000&repository=test&modelname=xxxxoptiona&submodelname=optionalsubmodel"

    
    ' generate boundary
    Dim BOUNDARY, s As String, n As Integer
    For n = 1 To 16
        
     s = s & Chr(65 + Int(Rnd * 25))
     Next
    BOUNDARY = s & CDbl(Now)
    
    Dim part As String, ado As Object
    part = "--" & BOUNDARY & vbCrLf
    part = part & "Content-Disposition: form-data; name=""file""; filename=""" & FILENAME & """" & vbCrLf
    part = part & "Content-Type: " & CONTENT & vbCrLf & vbCrLf
           
    ' read file into image
    Dim image
    Set ado = CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
    ado.Type = 1 'binary
    ado.Open
    ado.LoadFromFile PATH & FILENAME
    ado.Position = 0
    image = ado.read
    ado.Close
        
    ' combine part, image , end
    ado.Open
    ado.Position = 0
    ado.Type = 1 ' binary
    ado.Write ToBytes(part)
    ado.Write image
    ado.Write ToBytes(vbCrLf & "--" & BOUNDARY & "--")
    ado.Position = 0
   
   
    ' send request
    With CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP")
        .Open "POST", URL, False
        .setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "multipart/form-data; boundary=" & BOUNDARY
        .send ado.read
        Debug.Print .responseText
        
    End With

    MsgBox "File: " & PATH & FILENAME & vbCrLf & _
           "Boundary: " & BOUNDARY, vbInformation, "Uploaded to " & URL

End Sub

Function ToBytes(str As String) As Variant

    Dim ado As Object
    Set ado = CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
    ado.Open
    ado.Type = 2 ' text
    ado.Charset = "_autodetect"
    ado.WriteText str
    ado.Position = 0
    ado.Type = 1
    ToBytes = ado.read
    ado.Close

End Function
```

I have tried the above code in ERStudio, even though there is no error, it was not exported the image.

I need to export the image as form data using VBA - macro.